# Pgfplot - How to exactly align the legend in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, legend

I have a legend in my **pgfplots** and want to manually position it at a point where the legend does not cover any text or measurement points.

I know the axis property `legend pos=north west`, but it's not possible to position it at a custom location.
According to the documentation ([link](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/pgfplots.pdf)) only the following values are allowed:

> `/pgfplots/legend pos=south west|south east|north west|north east|outer north east`
>
> A style which provides shorthand access to some commonly used legend positions.

How can I move the legend so that it is at the right position in my plot?
[image]
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try writing something like this in `axis`

```
\begin{axis}[
...
legend style={at={(0.2,0.5)},anchor=north west},
...
]
```

You can change the coordinate value to match the requirement.

`at={(0,0)}` will draw it at the **lower left corner** of the axis and
`at={(1,1)}` will draw it at the **top right corner** of the axis.

Comment: Yeah very nice, thanks a lot!